# I'm trying to run the command =>./gradlew generateAabFlavor but Android Studio says it can't find the file(gradlew)

Tags: android, devops, android-app-bundle

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gradlew" (in directory "C:\Users\Suporte\digitaloffer\version2\mainfarmav2-android\app"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the specified file

I tried to execute this code ./gradlew generateAabFlavor to generate a new aab

Comment: Did you try to execute this command in the root of your project or inside of the app folder? Since this file exists in the root of your project

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.